# Condition for tangency

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

Find the condition on $a$ and $b$ such that the line $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$ is tangent to the curve $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$

I'm a bit weak at coordinate geometry so what I tried to do was differentiate to get the derivitive of y with respect to x and some how equate that to the slope of the given line. But this didn't work out.

Comment: But what did you try?

Comment: as you posted it, the "curve" is not a curve and the "line" is not a line: pls. add the RHS to them!

Comment: Sorry about the problems with the question...I have edited now

Comment: the given line should have only on intersection Point with the given curve

Comment: Just by symmetry you know that $a=b$ from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can see a good thing happening in this question.
That is, we can substitute as follows:

$x^\frac{1}{3}$=$\sin{\theta}$

$y^\frac{1}{3}$=$\cos{\theta}$

$x$=$\sin^3{\theta}$

$y$=$\cos^3{\theta}$

$\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ =$3\sin^2{\theta}$$\cos{\theta}$

$\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ =$-3\sin{\theta}$$\cos^2{\theta}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}$=$-\cot{\theta}$

Therefore,

$y-cos^3{\gamma}$=$-\cot{\gamma}${$x-\sin^3{\gamma}$}

Is the tangent equation.

{here ${\gamma}$=random taken value of ${\theta}$ which is the parameter at the tangency point}

Now,

Put $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$

You will get

$a$=$\sin{\gamma}$ $[\sin^2{\gamma}$+$\cos^2{\gamma}$]

=$\sin{\gamma}$

Similarly, you will get $b=\cos{\gamma}$

Therefore,

$a^2+b^2=1$

is the required condition.

Comment: Pls help with the editing process tho..can someone tell me how  the editing is done?

Comment: Put math expressions around dollar signs `$1-x^2$` is $1-x^2$. Use `\sin (x)` and `\cos (x)` for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. Use `\frac{a}{b}` for $\frac{a}{b}$ and lastly use `\left(` and `\right)` for big parenthesis $\left( \frac{1}{1-\cos^2 x} \right)$. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has been my greatest confusion.

Comment: How do I put theta and theta not

Comment: I did it. I somehow edited. Thank you for help

Comment: Greek is `\theta` for $\theta$ and `\dot{\theta}` for $\dot{\theta}$. Finally try `\ddot{\theta}` for $\ddot{\theta}$. Finaly for boldface and roman it is `\mathbf{f}(x)` $\mathbf{f}(x)$ and `\mathrm{Rot}(\theta)` $\mathrm{Rot}(\theta)$

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just searching when I found this on stackexchange:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Really helpful.